# .Reverse unable to be used within a map {case => if } Palindrome with second element

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and i'm unsure why this isn't working

```
def Palindrome[T](list: List[T]): Boolean = {

  list.zipWithIndex.map{case (num, i) => if(i%2 == 1) num == num.reverse}
  println(list)
}
```

I'm trying to make a palindrome checker based on every second element of a list. To my knowledge this should be working `IE List(1,10,2,5,2,10)` `10,5,10` is the palindrome

Comment: What your alg will return for `List(1,2,3,5,3,4,1)`? Something is wrong here?

Comment: thatll return false

Comment: Oh... now I understand. You need to get every second element from list and then check if it is palindrome... this is not some weird way of checking if something is palindrome.

Comment: In your code you are trying to call reverse on element of a list not list itself. It has no sense! Try to keep scala's naming convention (start methods name from small letter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it in two steps:

- filter every second item
- check if filtered collection is palindrome

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/IdZ2s5t/2

```scala
def dropEvenIndexes[T](list:List[T]) = {
  list.zipWithIndex
    .collect {case (it, idx) if idx % 2 ==1 => it }
}

def isPalindrome[T](list: List[T]): Boolean = list == list.reverse

def palindromeOddIndexes[T](l:List[T]) = isPalindrome(dropEvenIndexes(l))
```